# Can you change the width or height of a shape using openTBS?

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I was wondering if you could change the width of a shape with openTBS

I think the text should be written in the alt text box but I coudln't find any article that explained how to do that

Comment: is it for a DOCX or an ODT ?

Comment: It is for a DOCX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a DOCX, you can modify the width of text box, by placing this kind of TBS field inside the box :

```
[t;att=wp:extent#cx]
```

Then, you can merge the value at the PHP side using :

```
$TBS->MergeField('t', 3000000);
```

The unit is EMUs (English Metric Units). I don’t know about it, but is the [mentioned here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.drawing.wordprocessing.extent?view=openxml-2.8.1).